# HTTPWebRequest, How to prevent host/header value from changing case

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, httpwebrequest

I am using a HttpWebrequest (.Net 4.0) to talk to my server with this code. My problem is, the client object converts the 'Host' part of the request to lowercase (in my case "TETRA_20") before writing it to wire. Hence my server rejects this HTTP request.

Has someone faced a similar problem and fixed it? Is this an issue with the .Net framework?

```
HttpWebRequest client = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = client.Headers;
client.SendChunked = false;

if (hostAlias != null)
   client.Host = "TETRA_20";
client.UserAgent ="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0";                
client.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
client.KeepAlive = true;

myWebHeaderCollection.Set("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
myWebHeaderCollection.Set("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
myWebHeaderCollection.Set("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

WebResponse responseData = client.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Probably worth taking a read of the RFC for DNS case-sensitivity: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4343 (which is after all, what a host name is all about).

Comment: IMO, it's "your server" which is misbehaving here by keeping a notion of case-sensitivity.

Comment: @spender: this was an intentional implementation from the server guys

Comment: I think they got it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this through google. RFC2616 (section 3.2.3) states that **host header evaluation MUST be case insensitive**. So it is a good practice to set the Host header value to lower case before ...

**3.2.3 URI Comparison**

When comparing two URIs to decide if they match or not, a client SHOULD use a case-sensitive octet-by-octet comparison of the entire URIs, with these exceptions:

> - A port that is empty or not given is equivalent to the default
>     port for that URI-reference;
>
>   - Comparisons of host names MUST be case-insensitive;
>   - Comparisons of scheme names MUST be case-insensitive;
>   - An empty abs_path is equivalent to an abs_path of "/".

Comment: Thanks A-Dubb, but the server was intentionally implemented to be case sensitive. Isnt there something the client can do to avoid this conversion?

Comment: Is there no way you can make the server case insensitive? I think your server should conform to the spec if at all possible. If you want to circumvent the constraint enforced by the higher level API, then you'll most likely have to use a lower level implementation; sockets for example.

Comment: It's never a good idea to go off-roading with a standard. Even if you can get it to work, throw some random piece of hardware between the client and server (perhaps a proxy server?) and you might find you need to "fix" that too. Anybody recommending an approach that doesn't adhere to the standard will be wrong.